# Pythonanywhere MySQL-Connetion from outside

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

I tried to connect to my MySQL-Database from my Home-PC and got the error:
'Can't connect...'
Inside this Server with Skript and Konsole I've got no problems, but from outside it seems,
I have no chance...
Is there a way to connect from outside?
Perhaps with Creating a new User...

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can access your PythonAnywhere MySQL database (and other services)
from outside of PythonAnywhere only if you use a paid account, since
that requires SSH tunneling, and SSH is a paid feature.  See more on
the [official documentation page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/).